# Nuxt3 websocket client – Node.js Express websocket server – Best practice

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm pretty new to Nuxt3 and websocket. I have a node.js express application that needs to be the socket.io server.
When a user logs into the Nuxt3 app, the socket connection to node should be established and stay open until the user logs out or the browser is closed.

Therefore I created this plugin

*plugins/websocket.js*

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    const { status } = useAuth();

    if(status.value === 'authenticated') {
        const socket = io('http://localhost:1234')
        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('Connected to WebSocket server')
        })

        // store socket to global variable? pinia store?
    }

});
```

*and added this to nuxt.config.js*

```
 plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/websocket.js', mode: 'client' }
  ],
```

Now I'm wondering if this is a good approach and how I can access the socket to send something to the websocket server e.g. from a component.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!